# Router Disconnecting randomly ! Bad Password?

Tags: networking, router, ip, dhcp

I have been facing this irritating issue lately, and have exhaustively searched for simmilar issues online but didn't got it solved yet.

I am using a **D-link dual band route**r.These are the present settings of the router::

- encryption :: WPA 2 AES for both 2.4Ghz and %5Ghz band
- Group Key renewal :: set to 36000seconds
- IP lease time set for 7 Days
- DHCP IP reservation enabled for client (static ips mapped to mac address of clients, in my case just two clients)
- Bandwidth fixed to 20 Mhz for both band i.e 5Ghz and 2.4 Ghz
  Channels of both 2.4 Ghz and 5Ghz set to manual, to avoid interference with other (also interference ruled out by wifi analyser app) infrastructural wifi networks
  Multicast disabled

All other settings are default.

The router receives internet connection through a ethernet connection.

For the **client side** (my laptop) :

- OS :: linux 16.04
- network manager :: wicd
- ipv6 disabled
- Encryption :: WPA 1/2 (Hex[0-9/A-F])
- wicd is configured to only this network

I am using a tp link usb wifi adapter  to connect to network. Power management turned off, ipv6 disabled.

**Problem** :: the connection to network (either of the bands 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz is not stable. SOmetimes it remains connected for 40 50 mins but disconnects suddenly. Once disconnected it won't reconnect for 15-20 mins, but if I restart the router it will immediately reconnect.At wicd side even when the link strength is 80-100% (also in iwonfig) the connection does not gets established once disconnected, it also shows message "bad password".

Also as per 'dmesg' whenever it disconnects I can observe that it throws a "sta recv deauth reason code(6)" followed by code(2) and code(3) repeatedly multiple times.

At the router side I don't know how to get logs.

Interestingly, my laptop very smoothly connects to university network and is very stable even with poor link strength.

Please help me I have been struggling a lot past month.

Answer (score 0):

> " Once disconnected it won't reconnect for 15-20 mins, ....  once
> disconnected, it also shows message "bad password""

Reset to factory specs to eliminate the (possibly) defective wireless profile in the machine.

Then update the firmware in the router and set it up again.

**Follow up:**  This was a new router because the old router had a similar issue. Still upgrade firmware and reset to ensure all is well with the new router and then ask the ISP to consider replacing the modem.

Also, if the connection is not actively used on some device, check Power Management on the device to ensure it cannot turn off. However, this will not cause bad password - that is a router issue.

Comment: I had same issue in my old router but suspecting it to be hardware defect I purchased a new one recently (a week ago). The problem persists, and the above settings is with the new router. 

About the firmware, I am not sure.

I am a very newbie in this, but could it be an issue with some timeout parameter?

Comment: I have not see a timeout parameter in a wireless profile. That this is a new router, ask your ISP and suggest a new modem.

Comment: I don't think ISP is relevant to the case here. I am not concerned about the internet connection. My client pcs totally disconnects from the router irrespective of I have internet connection or not.

Comment: I am interested in setting up a network of connected pc and embedded devices (three in total) which can communicate over ssh through router. Internet is not necessary.

Comment: I added a note about Device Management, but the "bad password" is more likely a Router Issue.